# Node/Express app on Heroku: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am attempting to get my Node.js app (which runs perfectly fine on localhost) running on Heroku, but running into some issues. There have been a couple other questions answered with the same error, but none of the solutions have worked for me. Here is what I'm getting from the Heroku logs:

```
2016-12-28T22:06:45.705675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2016-12-28T22:06:48.358120+00:00 app[web.1]: Environment: HEROKU
2016-12-28T22:06:48.360021+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on PORT:13812
2016-12-28T22:06:49.226997+00:00 app[web.1]: Application Loaded...
2016-12-28T22:07:45.958705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-12-28T22:07:45.958927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-12-28T22:07:46.102423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-12-28T22:07:46.079295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-28T22:07:46.080349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Rinse and repeat. Here is what I get when I try to navigate to my URL after my application has started:

```
2016-12-28T22:16:57.209624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sc-library-test.herokuapp.com request_id=e98196c1-1545-4a49-9c20-f4ac7f2ab964 fwd="70.95.172.183" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Now for my code, particularly the bin/www file that comes with Express.

```
const config = require('../config');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = normalizePort(config.port || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Get hostname from environment.
 */
const host = config.host || 'localhost';

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port, host);

function normalizePort(val) {
  console.log("val: " + val);
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);
  console.log(port);
  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    console.log("nan");
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    console.log(">=0");
    return port;
  }
  console.log("false");
  return false;
}
```

I've tried doing the server.listen with and without the host, but I get the same error either way. Here is my config file:

```
module.exports = {
  port: process.env.PORT,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
    base_url: process.env.BASE_URL,
    auth: {
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID
  },
    neo4j_href : process.env.NEO4J_HREF,
  redis_url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
    redis_secret: process.env.REDIS_SECRET
}
```

As you can see I'm pulling the port from my heroku environment, along with the rest of my environment variables, and using it on my server.listen().

Some other information... I'm not currently using a Procfile. My app consists of a single web server, and since my app is running with the single web dyno and no workers without the Procfile, I assume that's fine. Correct me if I'm wrong.

EDIT: Here is my updated bin/www file, which is still giving me the same error.

```
const app = require('../app');
const config = require('../config');

const port = config.port || '3000';
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your node app isn't actually starting the web server correctly. It appears to me that your usage of `server.listen` is incorrect (see [the docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_options_callback)).

While you could always rewrite your `server.listen` call to pass in the correct object -- since you're using Express, there's actually a much easier way. Express ships with support for running the server using a convenient wrapper around the standard library stuff. Here's how you can re-write your code to use it:

```
const config = require('../config');

const port = config.port || '3000';
app.listen(port);
```

This will start the server, bind it to `0.0.0.0`, and make it listen on the desired port.

**NOTE**: you no longer need to parse the port into an integer, as this is handled by the abstraction layer.

Comment: I have tried it without using the host, with the same error. Are you saying that this line is unnecessary?

Comment: const server = http.createServer(app);

Comment: I updated my post with my bin/www file, but am still getting the same output to the logs as before.

Comment: Try putting the following code in your `bin/www` file ONLY: `var express = require('express'); var app = express(); app.listen(process.env.PORT);` That's a minimal express server / application, and if that doesn't work we can narrow it down further.